# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 install does not end

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I have a C# application with a Visual Studio Installer. This application needs to use SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I created a bootstrapper package following [this guide](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/how-about-a-bootstrapper-package-for-sqlserver-express-2008-r2/).

I have set this package as prerequisite in the Setup properties and generated the setup package.

When I start the Setup a dialog box ask for license agreement
[image]

Then the file is downloaded
[image]

And the install is performed
[image]

But this install never end on my Windows 7 (on Windows 10 all is OK). When the progress bar is complete, the loading restart. I have to restart the computer and relaunch the setup. The second time, SQL server is considered to be installed and the setup perform the next step (installing CLR types 2014)

How can do to unblock the setup ? Maybe asking user for reboot but I don't know how.

Thank you

**Edit**: I changed the package (from `SQL SERVER 2008 + .NET Framework 4.0` to `SQL SERVER 2008 + .NET Framework 4.0 Client`) and now the SQL install is OK but now this is the .NET Framework 4.0 Client who never end.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What is your RAM? Does your machine meet the minimum requirements?

Comment: I'm using a virtual machine for the tests. The machine have 4Go memory RAM. And it meet the requirements, application works fine if I install the prerequisites one by one.